# Embed drupal 7 node form

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, embed

I would like to know if it is possible to insert a node in a page. I work with Drupal 7 and I can not find how to do this.

Someone has an idea? I tried to do this:

```
    function test(){

       if (!function_exists('node_add')) {
        module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
       }

       print drupal_render(node_add('node_example'));

    }
```

My form is displayed but poorly. It is "on" my theme

Comment: what is this 'page' you'd like to add a node to?  Is it a page that is already displaying its own content or a page that is displaying a view?

Comment: This is a page of my module. In fact, it's a tab in my menu. And i would like to integrate my node form into this tab. I hope you understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I am understanding your question correctly.  The answer to my comment did help!  If it *is* a node form that you're trying to add to the menu, this is typically done with a hook_menu() function in Drupal.  Here is some sample code to get you started

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {

 // Here, substitute in the URL of your page.  It can be mymodule/add_content or whatever else you'd like
 $items['YOUR_PAGE_URL'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'title' => t('YOUR PAGE TITLE'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('your_node_function'),      // Here, you should put in the function that creates your node form
    'access arguments' => array('Administer content'),  // This is optional, you can require a user to have certain permissions set to access your page/form
 );

 return($items);

}
```

Remember to clear your cache before you test it!

Sample code in your function that is creating the form:

```
function your_node_function($form, &$form_state)
{
  $form['field_1'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Field label'),
   '#description' => t('Help user understand what to input here'),
   '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

See if you can see this tiny one-field form to get you started.  This doesn't explain how to actually save the user data, etc because that is outside the scope of what a single answer here can provide, but this should help you get started on a form that's hooked up to the menu system....

I hope this helped!!!!

=================== EDIT ===================

Here is online documentation for the different types of form elements you can add to forms in Drupal: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

Comment: Thanks its' better ! but i have some problems... : "undefined index : #node in comment_form_node_form_alter()" and "Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form_node_form_alter() " and "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form()"

Comment: Well those errors are originating with your function, not with my code above that hooks it up to the menu.

Comment: Also, it seem like you're altering a form that already exists, rather than creating your own form from start to finish.  Is that correct?  The reason that's confusing to me is that typically, when you're altering an existing form, you don't need to hook it up to the menu in this way, because that form already has its own path.  My suggestion was for a form that you're generating yourself (rather than amending an already existing form)... I don't know if that makes sense...

Comment: Ok but can i just use the article_node_form ? I've not function, right now, for my node form it's just tests. EDIT : OH ok ! i understand ! so it exists any other possibility to create a form manually ?

Comment: Yes, there's definitely another way to create a form (other than altering a form).  I'll edit my answer in a minute to include a small example...

Comment: Thank your for your help. I think i've understand how it works. Thank you